# Intervals in Guitar

Tags: guitar, intervals

I am a beginner guitar player trying to learn the basics. Currently I struggling with INTERVALS. I somewhere read the below section, but was not able to understand it properly.

**In Guitar, every string has a factor of 5**

-> When we go up : Same notes are located at **Fret + 5** (Except for 2 -> 3 : Fret + 4)

-> When we go down: Same notes are located at **Fret - 5** (Except for 3 -> 2 : Fret - 4)

I understood the `Same note at fret + 5 part` . But didn't quite get the exception part where it mentions
**2 -> 3** . Is it 2nd to 3rd fret or strings?

I would really appreciate if someone could  elaborate it for me. Thanks.

Comment: If the publication used the banner of 'intervals', it's quite misleading. Intervals themselves have a little to do with 'difference in number of frets', but other factors are also involved. Really, all you're asking about is how many frets different is one string on a guitar from another. Which John answers well. That's not strictly 'intervals'.

Comment: This question has almost nothing to do with intervals, except that the "factor of 5", "factor of 4" idea is about how to fret only _unisons_ on _adjacent_ strings which is a very specific case. If that was not explained in the resource, it seems very poorly written.

Comment: pranami, have you ever noticed you tune to the next string on the *fifth* fret, but with just the one exception?  that is all they are saying.  the book sounds pretty crappy :)  :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means that the distance, or factor as they call it between the 2nd and 3rd strings (B and G strings) is 4 half steps, or semitones instead of 5 between all other adjacent strings. The interval between all adjacent strings is a perfect 4th except for strings 3-2 (G-B), which is a major 3rd.

EDIT based on question in comment:

The practical application for this is if you play an open 1st (high E) string, in order to get that same note on the 2nd (B) string you finger it at the 5th fret.

If you play the open 2nd (B) string, in order to play that same note on the 3rd (G) string you finger it at the 4th fret.

Every other pair of strings, 3rd to 4th, 4th to 5th and 5th to 6th is a 5 fret difference, just like the 1st to 2nd.

It’s just simple math and is additive. For example, the 3rd fret on the 1st string is the same as the 8th fret on the second string. Also the 1st string open is the same as the 9th fret on the 3rd string (5+4).

It also works in the opposite direction. The 6th fret on the 6th (low E) string is the same as the 1st fret (-5) on the 5th (A) string.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. So does it mean that, if we want to get the same notes(Intervals) on strings 1st(High E) and 2nd string (string B), then for the E string it will note + 5 , and for string B, it goes to string + 4 ?

Comment: @pranami I edited my original answer to answer your question and give practical examples.

Comment: Wow, The explanation on the edit cleared my doubt. @John Belzaguy, Thanks a ton once again for your help. Appreciate it. Cheers :)

Comment: @pranami It was my pleasure. Don’t hesitate to post relevant questions anytime, there are a lot of people here that are more than willing to help.